# Lucene.Net - Get distinct categories

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I have created the following document:

```
var document = new Document();
document.Add(new Field("category", "foo", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
...
```

I have approx 10M documents which belong to 8 distinct categories. I would like to get all distinct categories (get all documents and read a value of `category` field) by executing search query. Is that feasible?

Another approach is to create a list of categories at index rebuild and to write these values in database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [IndexReader.Terms()](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_4/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#terms%28org.apache.lucene.index.Term%29) method.

If you give it an empty Term for a field, it will return a TermEnum containing all the terms for that field.

```
TermEnum terms = indexReader.Terms(new Term("category"));
// enumerate the terms
```

Comment: Problem with this is that it returns as many hits as there is entries in index. Let's say, I have 400K entries in 150K "categories". However, I will get 400K entries returned.

Answer (score 0):

To extend Beaulac's solution for future use...

To only get unique result set, you must iterate through terms like this:

```
while (null != terms.Term) {
    If (term.Field.Equals("category")) {
        // do something with this term
    }
    terms.Next();
}
```

Comment: good addition, but actually you should check the fieldname in your while condition, or break when the fieldname is not "category" anymore, since you'd be looping for no reason, the enum has already been positioned on the field.

Comment: I would have to check that, but as far as I tested, it can happen that one term is from specified field, another is not and the last one is again. Thus, I implemented a separate if. As I said, I have to check that, as I am not sure.